# Grid layout not working, php recent posts Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I am kind of a newbie on CSS and can't get my grid layout to work properly. I suspect that is has to do with the php WP_Query request because all my recent posts show up vertically in just one column of the grid.

I want them to display in 3 columns and 2 rows. I've tried everything and my code just keeps on getting messier..

Is there an easy way to do this?

This is how I want it to look:

[recent blog posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7SKQ.png)

my index.php code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="main">
  <div id="content">
    <!--    <div id="featuredPosts">-->
      <div class="item">
      </div>
      <div class="lastItem">
      </div>
    </div>-->
    <div class="grid-container">

      <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6' ); ?>
      <!--// Start our WP Query-->
      <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <!--     // Display the Post Title with Hyperlink-->
      <div class="grid-item">
        <article>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
          <!--      // Display the Post Excerpt-->
          <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
          <!--      Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit-->
        </article>
        <?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

my css code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer,
header,
nav,
  {
  display: block;
}

article {
  display: grid;
}

body,
html {}

#outer-wrapper {
  background-image: url(assets/Organizer2.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*  overflow: hidden;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#inner-wrapper {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.main {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 100px;
  /*  display: grid;*/
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}



header {
  /*  background: url(assets/Stina%20Smeds%20-%20Developer.png);*/
  /*
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
*/
  /*  o-background-size: cover;*/
  /*  padding: 15%;*/
  /*  width: 100%;*/
  height: 200px;
  /*  margin: auto 0;*/
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 20px;
  text-shadow: -3px 3px 6px #FFF;
}

#header p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffe6ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #29293d;
}

aside {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  float: right;
}

.aside-ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#content {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  /*  overflow: hidden;*/
  /*  margin-top: 25px;*/
  /*  display: grid;*/
  /*  text-align: center;*/
}

/*
#content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
*/

#content article {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  /*
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
*/
  /*  height: 200px;*/
  /*  width: 200px;*/
  /*  display: grid;*/
  /*  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
  /*  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr) repeat(3, 1fr);*/
  /*  grid-auto-flow: row;*/
  /*  grid: 270px 270px / repeat(4, 270px);*/
  /*  justify-content: center;*/
  /*  grid-gap: 10px;*/
  /*  padding: 10px;*/
  /*  border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

/*
.grid-item {
  border: solid 1px black;
  grid-auto-flow: column;

  grid-column: 2/3;

  grid-row: 1/3;

}
*/

.fa {
  /*  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;*/
  /*
  box-sizing: inherit;
  font-size: 70px;
*/
  color: #fea;
  text-shadow: -3px 3px 6px #79b4c2;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;

}

/* Add a hover effect if you want */

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


hr {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/*
#featuredPosts {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
*/

/*
#featuredPosts .item {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0 30px 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
}
*/

/*
#featuredPosts .lastItem {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
*/

/*
recentPosts {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
}
*/

/*
#content article.postBox {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 42px 30px 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: 4;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 290px;
}
*/

/*
.bg {
  background-image: url(assets/body-background.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
*/
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's better to make an `article` with a `grid-item` class instead of wrapping the article inside div. More convenient to style and for semantic purposes. It's not related to your problem so I'm writing this as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /* only two items here because you have 2 rows */
    /* auto is maximum height of item in a row */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
```

...and no grid-related items styling. The items will go to the cells in the same order they are in html. I don't think you should specify something else there. Snippet:

```css
.grid-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
.grid-item{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut lectus rutrum, tempus nulla sed, laoreet eros. Pellentesque massa neque, facilisis at metus eu, mollis rhoncus urna. Duis eleifend venenatis libero, rhoncus varius turpis tincidunt non.</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut lectus rutrum, tempus nulla sed, laoreet eros. Pellentesque massa neque, facilisis at metus eu, mollis rhoncus urna. Duis eleifend venenatis libero</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut lectus rutrum, tempus nulla sed, laoreet eros.</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut lectus rutrum, tempus nulla sed, laoreet eros. Pellentesque massa neque, facilisis at metus eu, mollis rhoncus urna.</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ut lectus rutrum, tempus nulla sed, laoreet eros.</div>
</div>
```

Also check [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited my code by removing the excess div around "article" and adding the grid code you wrote. It finally works, thank you so much!

Comment: @coderMom I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem ;)